# parameters not printing in jsp

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp

I have a web.xml that calls selectfoods.jsp first, the there is this form:

```
<form name="ingredientsform" method="post" action="table.jsp">
<select name="ingredients" multiple>
  <option value="tofu">Tofu</option>
  <option value="pepper">Pepper</option>
  <option value="spaghetti">Spaghetti</option>
  <option value="paprika">Paprika</option>
  <option value="onion">Onion</option>
  <option value="beef">Beef</option>
  <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

which forwards to table.jsp where I would like to print out the ingredients selected but no error appears just an empty page here is  the relevant code in the table.jsp

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Table</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table>
 <thead> <td> <b> Products </b></td></thead>
 <%
 String items[] = (String[]) request.getAttribute("ingredients");
 for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
 {
 %>
 <tr> <td> <% out.println(items[i]); %> </td> </tr>
 <%
 }
 %>
 </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Change this `request.getAttribute("ingredients")` to `request.getParameterValues("ingredients");` this will get multiple value selected from your `<select>` list

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using servlet-JSP MVC model for developing an application.
With MVC it would be easy to make a separate view and business logic and also it is easy to handle also.

To get parameter from submitted form , `request.getParameter()` is used not `request.getAttribute()`.

Here you have make multiple selections so you have to use `request.getParameterValues()` which will fetch all selected values.